# Very basic outlet/action connection issue in xcode4 and assistant editor

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode4, appdelegate

I have a brand new xcode 4 cocoa project ( not ios ) with a single window. For the view in that window I changed the class to "myView" and created myView.[hm] . I added a push button to the view of the main window. When I control-drag from the button to the source code for myView.m it doesn't popup with "create action?" as I would expect. It does, however, pop up when I try to control-drag to "AppDelegate.m". So I think I need to change an "owner" of something so the control-drags to myView.m work.

Any suggestions in how I might do that, or what I have conceptually wrong, would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Charlie

Comment: It doesn't make a lot of sense for views to talk to other views. Views should talk to a controller.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing two mistakes.

First : You have to do Ctrl+Drag to .h if you want it to make public, if you do it in .m it will become private. As you are unable to do in .m Please try it in .h.

Second: Change you Object's class to myView, by default it would be AppDelegate. And check what is your File's Owner class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; I wanted to add an action to the .m file not a outlet to the .h file that's why I was dragging to the .m file. What I want is the button to belong to my MyView class.

Comment: You *can* ctrl-drag to .m; you're simply limited in *where* in that file you can drag to. Also, there's no reason to assume that the top-level object that is the application's delegate is the view object that the questioner wants to connect.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where you drag to. You can't insert an outlet (which is a property) or an action method declaration in an `@implementation`, or at the top level of the .m file. You must insert them within an `@interface`.

At the top of the .m file, just above the `@implementation`, start writing an `@interface`, and take the completion for a class extension. It should look like this:

```
@interface MyView ()

@end
```

Ctrl-drag to between those two non-empty lines, and insert your outlet or action declaration there.

> So I think I need to change an "owner" of something so the control-drags to myView.m work.

I think what you read somewhere and are thinking of is changing the class of the File's Owner. You would only have to change it if it were not already the correct class, and even then, this would only be relevant if that object were on one end or the other of your ctrl-drag. Since you are dragging from one other object to the class of another, the File's Owner is not involved, so there is nothing about it that you can or should change to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following approach doesn't make use of the assistant editor:

First declare an action

```
@interface myView : NSView
//...
- (IBAction)myAction:(id)sender;
//...
@end
```

in `myView.h` or alternatively in a class extension

```
@interface myView ()
//...
- (IBAction)myAction:(id)sender;
//...
@end
```

in `myView.m`.

In Interface builder, control drag from the button to the `myView`

[image]

and select `myAction:`.